# How to set custmer id for an quote in magento?

Tags: magento-1.7, cart

I am adding product into cart and tried to map customer id,email to that quote
using the below code

```
            $product_id = 123; 
            $qty        = 1; 
            $product    = Mage::getModel('catalog/product')->load($product_id);
            $cart       = Mage::getModel('checkout/cart'); 
            $cart->init();

            $superAttributeArray = array('151' => '3');
            $params = array(
                        'product' => $product_id,
                        'qty'     => $qty,
                        'super_attribute' => $superAttributeArray
                         );
            $cart->addProduct($product, $params);
            $cart->save();

            $currenQuoteId = Mage::getSingleton('checkout/session')->getQuoteId();
            $store = Mage::getSingleton('core/store')->load(Mage::app()->getStore()->getId());
            $quote = Mage::getModel('sales/quote')->setStore($store)->load($currenQuoteId);

            $quote->setCustomerId('1')->setCustomerEmail('test@gmail.com')->setCustomerFirstname('firstname')->setCustomerLastname('lastname');
            $quote->save();
```

When I try to set customerid,email,fname,lname am getting error as "Mage registry key "controller" already exists".

Can anyone help me in fixing this issue?

Answer (score 0):

Something like this might work

```
$customerObj = Mage::getModel('customer/customer')->load($customerId);
$quoteObj    = Mage::getModel('sales/quote')->assignCustomer($customerObj);

$storeId = Mage::app()->getStore()->getId();
$quoteObj->setStore(Mage::getSingleton('core/store')->load($storeId);

$productObj = Mage::getModel('catalog/product')->load($productId);

$quoteItem = Mage::getModel('sales/quote_item')->setProduct($productObj);
$quoteItem->setQuote($quoteObj);
$quoteItem->setQty('1');
$quoteItem->setStoreId($storeId);
$quoteObj->addItem($quoteItem);

$quoteObj->setStoreId($storeId);
$quoteObj->collectTotals();
$quoteObj->save();
```